# How to add additional data to Excel file, so existing data won't be erased?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, openpyxl

I have a ready-made file with ready-made sheets, I just need to add data there for two columns. I want to add data to the existing database so that other data will not be erased

```
def teach_add():
df = pd.read_excel(open('bd1.xlsx','rb'),sheet_name='teachers')
print(df[['Teachers','Subjects']])
num = 2
ind  = int(input("Enter index: "))
for i in range(0, num):
    num2=input("Enter: ")
    num2 = num2.split(' ')
df.loc[ind]=[num2]
df.to_excel('bd1.xlsx', sheet_name='teachers')
```

Error:

> ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Comment: What is the data that you need in the two new columns?

Comment: the first column for the teacher, the second for the subject

Comment: Where exactly do you want to add this data? Do you want to append this data to some existing sheet? Please provide all such details in the question itself.

Comment: Yes, I want to add data to the existing database so that other data will not be erased

Comment: By database you mean `excel`? If yes, in which sheet you want to write into?

Comment: Yes, in excel, in sheet 'teachers'

Comment: As per your code, `teachers` sheet already has data for columns `'Teachers' and 'Subjects'`. What do you want to add then? Its confusing for me now.

Comment: I want to add new teachers and subjects they teach there

Comment: And these `new` teachers and `subjects` you want input from the user?

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Does your existing `df` has any other columns other than `Teachers` and `Subjects`? or these are the only ones?

Comment: only ones,,,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For preserving old sheets and writing to existing one, you need `openpyxl` library:

Do this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def teach_add():
    filename = 'bd1.xlsx'

    book = load_workbook(filename)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book

    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

    df = pd.read_excel(open('bd1.xlsx','rb'),sheet_name='teachers')
    nums = int(input("How many teachers and subjects you want to add?:"))
    new_list = []
    for i in range(nums):
        usr_input = input("Enter Teacher & Subject separated by space:")
        new_list.append(usr_input.split(' '))
    df = df[['Teachers','Subjects']]
    df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(new_list, columns=df.columns))
    
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='teachers')
```

Comment: everything is cool, but the rest of the sheets in the file are gone

Comment: and even your previous code deleted all sheets in the file, how to fix this bro?

Comment: You would need to install `openpyxl`. Once you install it, refer to my updated answer.

Comment: You can install it by `pip install openpyxl`.

Comment: Sheets are not deleted, but data is not saved in the sheet